# How to set an image for UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to notify an user, but I don't like the standard UIAlertController design, I need to show a notification with my background image and custom colors so that every widget of my application is in the same style.

What are my options?
Can I simply implement a custom view and present it modally?
Could you point me to a good tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

you can customize `UIAlertController` at some level like you can change it's `tintcolor`,can set `attributed title`, can set `image` etc like,

```
   alertController.view.tintColor = [UIColor black];  //tint color

   NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString= [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"your string"];
 [attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
          value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:40.0]
          range:NSMakeRange(3, 7)];
 [alertController setValue:attributedString forKey:@"attributedTitle"];


  UIAlertAction *action= [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"title" 
                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

  }];
  UIImage *img= [UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"];
  [action setValue:img forKey:@"image"];
```

but if you want totally customized `alertcontroll` then you should use separate `uiview` or `viewcontroller` and should present it!

you can refer [nhhipster's tutorial](http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/) to know how  to play with `alertcontroll`.

Comment: thank you, I shall try it, if every thing is ok, I will accept your answer, btw can you write it also in swift, I am not familiar with object C syntax